# How to create long-running user data export for a Firebase app?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase app that uses **Firestore** as the database, **Storage** to store user's photos and **Functions** for various things. I want to be a good citizen and give my users a way to zip up all their data and download it, if they decided to leave me one day.

My plan is to do this:

1. Create a Zipped file write stream to a export **Storage Bucket**
2. Loop over all the user's **Storage** files and add them to the Zipped output stream.
3. Loop over the user's **Firestore** data, turn it into a JSON doc and add it to the zipped output stream.
4. Email the user with a download link for the zipped file.

But this is where I seem to hit the limitations of what **Functions** can do. After all, this export can take much longer than 9 minute time limit of a **Functions** call if I have years worth of photos to export.

What is the best solution for this problem?

I don't want to answer my own question, but having done my research, it seems that perhaps an option would be to add **Google Cloud Tasks** and **Google Cloud AppEngine** to my application architecture, but since neither is mentioned in the standard Firebase Console, I'm hesitant as they don't seem to be part of the 'Firebase vision'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add App Engine to your project, seeing as the 9 minute duration limit can't be increased [1]

App Engine is usually added to Firebase projects when you need to do additional backend logic [2] [3]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits

[2]https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#matrix

[3]https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#google_app_engine